# JS open dialog for select XML file and upload its content to server

Tags: javascript, html

i am using the following JS, but it seems that the selected file is not yet loaded to the input html element. how can i load a file by the input element and get what the user selected, is there an event or some other way to achieve that? (when using inspect elements on chrome it works - var file is not null)

```
function CreateNewReport() {

if (window.File && window.FileReader && window.FileList && window.Blob) {

    debugger;

    var input = $(document.createElement('input'));
    input.attr("type", "file");
    input.attr("id", "fileName");
    input.trigger('click'); // opening dialog

    debugger;

    var file = input[0].files[0];
    var reader = new FileReader();

    // Closure to capture the file information.
    reader.onload = (function (theFile) {
        return function (e) {

            debugger;
            var sXml = e.target.result;
            var eXml = encodeURIComponent(sXml);

            var postData = {

                reportXmlLayout: eXml
            };

            OpenNewWindow(postData, "ReportDesign/LoadLayoutFromXML");

        };
    })(file);

    if (file == null) 
        alert('File not loaded'); //always get here without inspect
    else
        // Read in the file as a data URL.
        reader.readAsText(file);


    return false;
}
else {
    alert('The File APIs are not fully supported by your browser.');
}

return false;
```

}

Answer (score 0, accepted):

i have managed to find a solution by register to onchange event, now my script looks like that and it works fine.

```
function CreateNewReport() {

if (window.File && window.FileReader && window.FileList && window.Blob) {

    debugger;

    var input = $(document.createElement('input'));
    input.attr("type", "file");
    input.attr("id", "fileName");

    input[0].onchange = function (e) {

        debugger;
        var file = input[0].files[0];
        var reader = new FileReader();

        // Closure to capture the file information.
        reader.onload = (function (theFile) {
            return function (e) {

                debugger;
                var sXml = e.target.result;
                var eXml = encodeURIComponent(sXml);

                var postData = {

                    reportXmlLayout: eXml
                };

                OpenNewWindow(postData, "ReportDesign/LoadLayoutFromXML");                    
            };
        })(file);

        if (file == null)
            alert('File not loaded');
        else
            // Read in the file as a data URL.
            reader.readAsText(file);
    };

    input.trigger('click'); // opening dialog

    return false;
}
else {
    alert('The File APIs are not fully supported by your browser.');
}

return true;
```

}